# Question ban reinstated after well received question

Tags: support, bug, post-ban

[I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), that when I get banned, I'll have to wait 6 month to get a new opportunity to ask a question. If the question was well received, I'd be able to ask a next one, and if not, my ban would be reinstated.

[My new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575362/verifyerror-on-tomcat-7-production-server-probably-caused-by-apache-commons-logg) was well received but my ban has been reinstated. How is that possible?

Comment: The ban is more of a rate limiting. Essentially, when you try to ask a new question it looks over all your old ones and calculates if you're allowed to or not. If you're not, you can only ask if your last question was 6 months ago. So in your case it may take many new good questions to get the system to consider you allowable again, each 6 months apart.

Comment: The [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/163863) seems to have worked in your favor; you don't appear to be blocked any more.

Comment: @Matt banned again....

Comment: Interesting to me that OPs new question looks pretty good (compared to a lot of the junk I see on the Android tag). A brief click through his profile onto other past questions and they also look pretty good. Surely there must be a lot more to this story than one can read on this page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you have some misconceptions about how the question ban works.

From the [help page you quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.

That means, every time you try to ask a question, the system will look at *all* your questions, deleted or undeleted, and check whether your overall contributions are positive or not (The exact weights / algorithms are unknown to us on purpose). If the system determines you to be a positive contributor, it will allow you to ask a question. If not, then no.

Also in there is this:

> Begin by fixing your existing questions: they should be clear,
>   specific and on-topic.

This is the most important part of the entire thing. We expect you to **fix** and improve your existing questions, not simply ask new ones.

Also take notice of this:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the
>   chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that
>   question is positively received, you **may** be able to continue asking
>   questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Emphasis mine.

This means your strategy only works if your one asked question is positive enough to let the system think that you're now a positive contributor.

Comment: Is possible solution requiring from support account deletion and create new one? I'm getting really desperate of it.

Comment: No. But you should _Begin by fixing your existing questions: they should be clear, specific and on-topic_. Being desperate will work as a great incentive for you to get on with it. :)

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný You can do that, but the question ban will carry over to your new account.

Comment: @Magisch if a question ban carries over to a new account, it's probably _hard_ to improve deleted questions of the old account, as they are invisible to the new account. So I hope the carrying over only applies to accounts with the exact same email address, so that there is a way to actually retrieve a potentially lost password of the old account. And in that case, creating an account with a different email address would effectively unlock the situation.

Comment: @Cœur: SO has only a certain amount of patience for those with more energy to spend trying to circumvent question blocks than asking good questions, so while there's probably some effort made to allow for such cases, they're far from a high priority for development effort.

Comment: The main trouble with editing past questions is that they might be outdated enough to not get any attention from relevant audience, and with some of the -4 ranked ones of OP, are likely to attract more negative responses even if properly edited. People grow, become more mature, but this system kinda treats them as kids based on their past transgressions. Kinda stupid, if someone would ask me.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný, The question ban does not carry over if you create a new account with a new email address. However, you need to be careful not to use your multiple accounts for nefarious purposes (ie, don't vote for yourself or give yourself a bounty, etc.).